# MYSQL advanced sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table full of id's (tID) which are created with a "w" in the beginning followed by a number (int) a dot and another number (int).

Sample id's:

```
w1.3, w1.12, w1.1, w1.1, w2.10, w2.4
```

When I use `ORDER BY tID` the returned array is

```
w1.1, w1.12, w1.2, w1.3, w2.10, w2.4.
```

I would like it to be

```
w1.1, w1.2, w1.3, w1.12, w2.4, w2.10
```

Is this possible within a MYSQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But you should consider storing only the 2 integers, without the `w` and in 2 columns.

In the meantime, you can use this:

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(tID, 'w', ''), '.', 1) AS SIGNED INT)
  , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tID, '.', -1) AS SIGNED INT)
```

Comment: As there are not that many entries so far I will probably go with this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible

```
select *
  from sorting 
 order by cast(substring(tID,2) as DECIMAL);
```

Be warned, these functions needs to operatate on every row in the table so if it's big consider using something else.

Comment: This now puts w1.12 infront of w1.1 unlike before.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more efficient to just pass the results back and do the sorting in the language that's calling MySQL.

For example:

```php
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from `sorting`");
    $arr = []; // Array() before PHP 5.4
    while($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $arr[] = $a;
    usort($arr,function($a,$b) { // use create_function before PHP 5.3
        return strnatcasecmp($a['tID'],$b['tID']);
    });
    // $arr is now ordered the way you wanted it in the query
    // but there is no ordering in MySQL, which may improve performance
    // depending on the database engine you're using.
?>
```